# Store a style in spatialite using pyqgis and pyspatialite

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, spatialite

Does someone knows is there a method of a qgis class to store styles to a postgis stored style. I know I can save a qlm file but I'm a searching for an alternative to this.

As an alternative I try to store vector styles in a spatialite database using pyspatialite. First a create the tables to store it `SELECT CreateStylingTables();`. I'm fine from taht point but 
I'm struggling with the sql function `select RegisterVectorStyledLayer();`. I set the name of the table and it geometry column, as it said in the documentation, but I have a message error that says the function doesn't exists.

I would really want to do as qgis does from gui (layer properties/save style in database). So I'm searching for a piece of code to do this.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [documentation for SpatiaLite SQL functions](http://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/spatialite-sql-4.3.0.html), the function should be **SE_RegisterVectorStyledLayer** (and not RegisterVectorStyledLayer as stated above)